# Java 8 web application memory leak issue in Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, java-8, java-7

Recently we migrated one of web application from java 7 to java 8. when we deploy the application in tomcat 7 server we are seeing a memory leak, where as when we deploy the same code in java 7 and tomcat 7 we are not seeing any memory issue. before i am gonna do further memory analysis i would like to know is there any one faced such a issue, if so how you resolved.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

i faced this type issue before. that happened because of, including lot of unwanted scripts(like js,css etc..),and also tried to remove unwanted dependencies. tomcat's default limit is 50mb, if your war size is much larger than default, there is also a chance for memory leak.